# Slight confusion with linked lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm reading about [linked lists and their implementation in C on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Language_support). I haven't picked up on them as quick as other C concepts.

In the `list_add()` function, I am wondering why it says...

```
n->next = *p; /* the previous element (*p) now becomes the "next" element */
```

I don't really understand the comment. Why would the previous element become the next? Shouldn't the new node become the next on the old node?

Remember, I've just started looking at linked lists, so walk me through it slowly.

Thanks.

#### Update

Sorry if it wasn't obvious, but all the code I am looking at is on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Language_support).

Comment: Can you give some details of the program.

Comment: May be the program is adding new nodes before the existing ones

Comment: @Shweta [Follow the link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Language_support) - that is all I'm looking at.

Comment: How do you get a score of 21,500 on stackoverflow.com and _not understand linked lists_?????

Comment: @alex: there's any number of ways to implement a linked list.  To understand what's been done, and why, we'd need to see the code and related structures.

Comment: @PP I'm a web developer who has just started looking at C. Therefore all my programming experience is with high level languages like JavaScript and PHP. Also, rep does not indicate programming ability - more *how long can you spend on this site and look like you know what you are talking about* :P

Comment: It is adding the new node n as the first node to the linked list. So p which contains the address of first node becomes its next i.e. the address of first node comes in the new node's next part. Now as p contains the address of first node which should be n, p is updated by assigning the address of n to it. So now n becomes first node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a simplest linked list implementation, new nodes are added to the front of the list, because it's easier.  You only need a single pointer to the first node of the list and you don't have to search through the list to find the end.   A more complex implementation might keep a front and end pointer in order to add to either end of the list.

Comment: The comment before the function states: "Parameters: **p is the node that we wish to insert at. if the node is the null insert it at the beginning". So the insertion done by list_add is not necessarily at the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

Because the list is single-linked, meaning it goes `A->B->C->etc`, it would have to iterate through the entire list to add the new element at the end.

Instead it adds the new element `n` at the start, and points `n->next` to the previous first element `p`.

Comment: The method list_add doesn't necessarily adds the new item on the start, it can insert the item into the middle of the list as well. The comment to the function clearly states this.

Comment: Actually, if you pass an element that is not the first, you would alter the chain. Imagine you have the chain `A->B->` and you insert `Q` with `B` as the passed element, you would get two chains: `A->B->C` and `Q->B->C` as you cannot go "back" and alter `A->next`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the method adds the new node to the *start* of the list, that is the newly created node becomes the new first node in the list.

General way of adding a new node at the beginning of the list:

```
// allocate new node pointed by new_node and fill it.

// make new node the first node by making it's next point to current head.
new_node->next = head; 

// head should always point to the beginning of the list.
head = new_node;
```

Answer (score 2):

The list_add function **doesn't necessarily** add a new node at the beginning of the list -- it just adds a new node that will be located before `p`.

The argument `p` could indirectly point to the node at the beginning of the list, or any other node in the list.

This code then makes a new node that has it's `next` field set to whatever `p` is pointing at.

**Updated:**

This code uses a pointer-to-pointer-to-node trick that is very useful when dealing with linked lists.  If you're seeing linked lists for the first time, this can be confusing.  But you should take the time to understand it, because it's an excellent example of the power of pointers.

In the code, `p` points to a pointer, which then points to a node.  This means `p` can indirectly point at the first node in the list:

[image: pointer to pointer usage in a linked list]

...which means `add_node` will insert a new node at the beginning of the list.  But `p` can also point indirectly at other nodes in the list:

[image: more pointer to pointer usage]

In this second example, `add_node` will insert a new node between the first and second nodes in the list.

Comment: Not really true: p should point to a _link_ from any of the nodes. After all, pointer to a node is not of type `LLIST**`, it's just `LLIST*`.

Comment: @Vlad:  I didn't want to add extra confusion by getting into the pointer-to-pointer thing, but you are absolutely correct.  I've edited this answer slightly to avoid saying the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

The new node is appended to the start of the existing list.

[0] [1] [2] + [n]
 =[n] [0] [1] [2]

Answer (score 1):

`list_add` function appends an element to the start of the list. So this comment means that our new element (`n`) has to point to old head of the list (`p`):

`[p]->[1]->[2] + [n] ==> [n]->[p]->[1]->[2]`

New node should be next of the old node if we would add an element to the end of the list:

`[0]->[1]->[p] + [n] ==> [0]->[1]->[p]->[n]`

Answer (score 1):

The function `list_add` gets `p`, which is the pointer to link (the pointer as well), which points to the element before which we need to insert the new data. `n` is the newly allocated node, so `n->next = *p;` basically says "the next link of the new node is set to point the node pointed by `*p`".

```
... [data, next]    >[data, next]   > >[data, next] ...
              |    |        ^ |    | |
               ----         |  ---   |
                            |        |
[p] ------------------------         |
[n] ------> [data, next]             |
                     |               |
                      ---------------
```

(we are setting the last link, going from [n]->[...next])

The comment in the code is definitely confusing. Better would have been "set the next list item of the new item to be the item which was the pointed to by the given link". Which is definitely overly verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding it to an index, so it pushed "p" up one node so the new node can slot in to the index of the previous p

Answer (score 0):

In linked list you can add your new node anywhere.
Suppose you want to add a node in the starting of the linked list you can do it by
n->next=start;//new node's next pointing towards the first node
start=n;//new node becomes first node
The way you have problem with is adding a new node before a given node